# CSS/Weebly: Changing site-title font

Tags: html, css, weebly

I'm trying to change my site-title font on weebly. But unfortunately, it won't work.
I've tried some youtube tutorials but they didn't help. 
I would like to have this font as site-title. (https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/7ad138835c0cf9f05a9f0ab343247612)
Hereby my css code and a screenshot, so I hope you can help me :)
Thank you in advance!

Screenshot: http://i66.tinypic.com/znu1aa.png[/IMG

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);
@font-face {font-family: "PNS";
    src: url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/7ad138835c0cf9f05a9f0ab343247612.eot");
    src: url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/7ad138835c0cf9f05a9f0ab343247612.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/7ad138835c0cf9f05a9f0ab343247612.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/7ad138835c0cf9f05a9f0ab343247612.woff") format("woff"),
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/7ad138835c0cf9f05a9f0ab343247612.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/7ad138835c0cf9f05a9f0ab343247612.svg#ProximaNovaSoftW03-Bold") format("svg");
}
/* Resets */
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
pre,
form,
body,
html,
p,
blockquote,
fieldset,
input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Global Styles */
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222121;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 24px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
a {
  color: #1cadeb;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #1894c9;
}
a img {
  border: 0;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
h2 {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
blockquote {
  margin: 2em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: url("quotes.png") no-repeat 0px 25px;
  color: #666666;
  border-left: 0px !important;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 28px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder,
:-moz-placeholder,
::-moz-placeholder,
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #666666;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border: 0px solid #93c4d3;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: '';
}
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2ad !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
}
input[type="radio"]:after {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: " ";
}
input[type="radio"]:checked,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  border: 1px solid #1cadeb !important;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
  background: #1cadeb;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:after {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 6px;
  border: solid #666666;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  display: block;
  border-color: #1cadeb;
  content: " ";
}
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Editor Overrides :: DO NOT REMOVE */
#icontent .wrapper .paris-header,
#preview-iframe .landing-page .wrapper .paris-header,
#icontent.landing-page .wrapper .paris-header,
#icontent .wrapper .banner,
#preview-iframe .landing-page .wrapper .banner,
#icontent.landing-page .wrapper .banner {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
#preview-iframe .landing-page .banner-wrap,
#icontent.landing-page .banner-wrap {
  height: 95vh;
  min-height: 95vh;
}
body.fade-in-nav .paris-header {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Mobile app */
body.wsite-checkout-page .paris-header,
body.wsite-native-mobile-editor .paris-header {
  position: absolute !important;
}
/* Header + Navigation */
.paris-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: #93c4d3 ;
  border-top: 5px solid #93c4d3 ;
  opacity: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
}
.paris-header .container {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.paris-header .logo {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}
.paris-header .logo a {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}
.paris-header .logo a img {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 50px;
}
.nav {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 1115px;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: background 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: background 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: background 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: background 500ms ease;
  transition: background 500ms ease;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 22px 20px;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: normal;
}
.nav li.wsite-menu-item-wrap#active > a,
.nav li.wsite-menu-subitem-wrap#active > a,
.nav li.wsite-menu-item-wrap > a:hover,
.nav li.wsite-menu-subitem-wrap > a:hover {
  background: #1cadeb;
}
.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
}
/* Submenus */
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #303030;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: #ffffff;
  border-left: 5px solid #1894c9;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu-arrow {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 0;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu-arrow:before {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  content: '\203A';
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 11px;
}
/* Mini cart */
#wsite-mini-cart {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 80px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 600px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
#wsite-mini-cart .wsite-css-aspect {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
/* Banner */
.banner-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 55px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff url('default-bg.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.banner-wrap:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  content: ' ';
}
.banner-wrap .container {
  display: table;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.banner-wrap .banner {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.banner-wrap .banner h2 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  word-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
.banner-wrap .banner p {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .button-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button {
  text-align: center !important;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #1cadeb;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button:hover .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #1894c9;
}
/* Content */
.main-wrap {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.main-wrap .content-wrap {
  padding: 40px 0 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
/* Footer */
.footer-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #222121;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.footer-wrap .wsite-footer {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 35px 0 20px;
}
.footer-wrap h2 {
  color: #989794;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: normal;
}
.footer-wrap p {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 0 15px;
}
.footer-wrap blockquote {
  background: url("quotes.png") no-repeat 0px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.footer-wrap .wsite-form-container {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
.footer-wrap .wsite-form-label,
.footer-wrap .form-radio-container {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/* Social */
.wsite-social .wsite-social-item {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
/* Buttons */
.wsite-button {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.wsite-button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.wsite-button .wsite-button-inner {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background: #cccbc6;
  color: #333333 !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  white-space: normal;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.wsite-button.wsite-button-large {
  background: none;
}
.wsite-button.wsite-button-large .wsite-button-inner {
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
}
.wsite-button:hover .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #b2b2ad;
}
.wsite-button.wsite-button-highlight {
  background: none;
}
.wsite-button.wsite-button-highlight .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #1cadeb;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
.wsite-button.wsite-button-highlight:hover .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #1894c9;
}
.wsite-button-large.wsite-button-highlight {
  background: none;
}
/* Forms */
.wsite-form-label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}
.wsite-form-sublabel {
  display: none;
}
.wsite-form-radio-container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}
.wsite-form-radio-container label {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
.wsite-form-input,
.wsite-search-element-input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 8px !important;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2ad;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-transition: border 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: border 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: border 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: border 300ms ease;
  transition: border 300ms ease;
}
.wsite-form-input:focus,
.wsite-search-element-input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #1cadeb;
}
.form-select,
.wsite-form-field select,
.wsite-com-product-option-groups select {
  height: auto;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #ffffff url(select-dropdown.png) 97% center no-repeat;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2ad;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-transition: border 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: border 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: border 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: border 300ms ease;
  transition: border 300ms ease;
}
.form-select:focus,
.wsite-form-field select:focus,
.wsite-com-product-option-groups select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #1cadeb;
}
.formlist,
.wsite-editor .formlist {
  min-height: inherit;
}
.form-field-error .wsite-form-radio-container {
  border: none;
}
.form-field-error .wsite-form-radio-container input[type="radio"],
.form-field-error .wsite-form-radio-container input[type="checkbox"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.wsite-search-element-submit,
.wsite-editor .wsite-search-element-submit {
  top: 12px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
/* Gallery */
.imageGallery {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.imageGallery * {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.imageGallery .galleryCaptionHolder {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.imageGallery .galleryCaptionHolder:hover .galleryCaptionHolderInnerBg {
  background: #1894c9;
  opacity: .8;
}
.imageGallery .galleryCaptionHolderInner {
  height: 100%;
}
.imageGallery .galleryCaptionHolderInnerBg {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.imageGallery .galleryCaptionInnerTextHolder {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.imageGallery .fullImageGalleryCaption .galleryCaptionInnerTextHolder {
  position: relative;
}
.imageGallery .galleryCaptionInnerText {
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}
/* Fancybox overrides */
.fancybox-skin {
  background: transparent !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
.fancybox-title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}
.fancybox-close,
.fancybox-next span,
.fancybox-prev span {
  background: none !important;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.fancybox-close:before,
.fancybox-next span:before,
.fancybox-prev span:before {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 0.75em;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.fancybox-close:hover:before,
.fancybox-next:hover span:before,
.fancybox-prev:hover span:before {
  color: #1cadeb !important;
}
.fancybox-prev span:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  content: '\3008';
}
.fancybox-next span:before {
  position: relative;
  right: -10px;
  content: '\3009';
}
.fancybox-close {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
.fancybox-close:before {
  content: '\00D7';
}
/* Landing Page */
.landing-page .banner-wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.landing-page .banner-wrap .banner {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}
.landing-page #contentArrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.landing-page #contentArrow span {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  left: 10px;
  content: '\203A';
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 11px;
}
.landing-page #contentArrow span:before,
.landing-page #contentArrow span:after {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 4px;
  height: 16px;
  content: ' ';
}
.landing-page #contentArrow span:before {
  top: 5px;
  left: 4px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.landing-page #contentArrow span:after {
  top: -11px;
  left: 13px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.landing-page #contentArrow:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Fade In */
.landing-page.fade-in .banner {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Tall Header Page */
.tall-header-page .banner-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 450px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.tall-header-page .banner-wrap .container {
  height: 450px;
}
.tall-header-page .banner-wrap .banner h2 {
  font-size: 70px;
  padding-top: 65px;
}
/* Short Header Page */
.short-header-page .banner-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 240px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.short-header-page .banner-wrap .container {
  height: 240px;
}
.short-header-page .banner-wrap .banner h2 {
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 65px;
}
/* No Header Page */
.no-header-page .main-wrap {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
/* Splash Page */
.splash-page {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.splash-page .wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.splash-page .main-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(default-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.splash-page .main-wrap:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  content: ' ';
}
.splash-page .main-wrap > .container {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 6em 0 4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.splash-page .main-wrap .content-wrap {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: none;
}
.splash-page .main-wrap .splash-content h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
}
.splash-page .main-wrap .splash-content p {
  padding: 0 0 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.splash-page .footer-wrap {
  display: none;
}
/* Old styles */
#commentArea {
  border-top: solid 1px #dadada;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#wsite-content #commentAreaTitle {
  font-size: 26px;
}
#wsite-content #commentAreaTitle,
#wsite-content #commentReplyTitle,
#commentArea .blogCommentText p,
.main-wrap .blog-sidebar h2 {
  padding: 0;
}
#commentAreaTitle {
  font-family: 'fjalla-one', sans-serif;
}
.blogCommentHeading,
.blogCommentText p {
  font-family: inherit;
}
.blogCommentWrap {
  background: none;
}
.blogCommentWrap .blogCommentHeading,
.blogCommentWrap .blogCommentHeadingInner,
.blogCommentWrap .blogCommentAuthor {
  background: none !important;
}
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentAuthor span.name,
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentAuthor span.email {
  color: #2a92e5 !important;
  float: none;
}
.blogCommentHeading {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentAuthor,
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentDate {
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
}
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentAuthor {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentDate {
  color: #999;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.blogCommentText {
  padding: 0;
}
.blogCommentText p {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentHeadingInner {
  height: auto;
}
.blogCommentWrap .blogCommentHeading .blogCommentHeadingInner .blogCommentAuthor .name {
  text-shadow: none;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #3b3b3b !important;
  float: none;
}
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentHeadingInner .blogCommentAuthor .link {
  margin: 0 5px;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentAuthor,
.blogCommentHeading .blogCommentDate {
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

I cut some of the code, it was to long to submit, but I only deleted the @mediascreen parts of it :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you aren't actually assigning the font:

```
h2 {
/*  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif; */
    font-family: 'PNS', sans-serif;
}
```